# How to get word wrap to wrap at smaller widths

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a line of text to word wrap  while it displays next to the image. When the text is too long it puts the text under the image, and then it will do word wrap. How can I get the text to wrap so it fits next to the image at all widths?

In my example I included what I mean by next to the image, and what I mean by not wrapping until under the image. All I have come up with to try is changing the width of `#ItemText` and that does not produce the desired results.

```css
#Items{
    text-align:left;
    display:block;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width:300px;
    background-color:gray;
}
#imgItem{
    display:inline-block;
}
#ItemText{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.ItemName{
    display:block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ItemNum{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Items">
    <img id='imgItem' height="100" width="50" src='s.jpg' />
    <div id="ItemText">
        <div class="ItemName">
            This text is short enough
        </div>
        <div class="ItemNum">
            AB503
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="Items">
    <img id='imgItem' height="100" width="50" src='s.jpg' />
    <div id="ItemText">
        <div class="ItemName">
            This text doesn't wrap until it goes under the image
        </div>
        <div class="ItemNum">
            AB503
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does `ItemText` _need_ to be an inline-block? If so, make it narrower (it should be the width of Items minus the width of the image minus a space). If it doesn't need to be an inline-block, you can float the img. Oh, and don't use duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Without adding any css to a `<p>`, it defaults to wrapping around `float`ing elements.  We can achieve what you want by removing a majority of your css and simply `float`ing the image to the left and changing your `<div>`s to `<p>`s.

## HTML

```
<div id="items">
    <div class="item">
        <img class="item-image" height="100" width="50" src='s.jpg' />
        <p class="item-name">This text doesn't wrap until it goes under the image</p>
        <p class="item-num">AB503</p>
    </div>
</div>

#items{
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

## CSS

```
.item {
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item-image {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px
}

.item-name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.item-num {

}
```

That will wrap the text nicely within the `.item` div. Note that because the image is `float`ing, you'll need to set a `min-height` on the `.item` div to prevent your image from extending past the bounds of the `.item` div.  I also added some padding to to keep the content away from the edges.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply new margins based on the image dimensions like so: https://jsfiddle.net/L6v60u03/

**HTML**

```
<div class="Items">
    <img class='imgItem' height="100" width="50" src='http://theartmad.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Smiley-Face-5.jpg' />
    <div class="ItemText">
        <div class="ItemName">This text is short enough</div>
        <div class="ItemNum">AB503</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="Items">
    <img class='imgItem' height="100" width="50" src='http://theartmad.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Smiley-Face-5.jpg' />
    <div class="ItemText">
        <div class="ItemName">This text doesn't wrap until it goes under the image</div>
        <div class="ItemNum">AB503</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Items{
    text-align:left;
    display:block;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width:300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:gray;
}
.imgItem{
    display:inline-block;
}
.ItemText{
    display:block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.ItemName{
    display:block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ItemNum{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**JS**

```
var width = $(".imgItem").css("width");
var height = $(".imgItem").css("height");
var trueWidth = parseInt(width) + 10; // Adjust padding by adding more
var trueHeight = parseInt(height) * -1 + 10; // Adjust padding by adding more
$(".ItemText").css("margin-left", trueWidth);
$(".ItemText").css("margin-top", trueHeight);
```